# Register Twilio as extension/endpoint SIP client using username and password

Tags: twilio, sip

I have the next situation:
  A call is made to a PSTN/DID number of my phone company and that I can use with proprietary SIP cell phone app or SIP client application like Zoiper / Linphone configuring with SIP, user and password.

I cannot configure this service to forward a call to 3rd party service SIP URI. I've already asked it to my PSTN provider and they say that it is impossible.

The question is:
 How can I make Twilio  (or maybe another service) register as SIP client with user and password (like extension/endpoint ) to receive a call from PSTN and forward it to other SIP URI or phone number?

I know that asterisk / some cloud pbx can do it like it was previously free account at pbxes.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered porting your number to a carrier that will allow you to forward inbound calls to a specific SIP URI you configure or register for calls to that URI, given your current carriers constraints?

For example, Twilio has some documentation here on porting a number.

[International Porting](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226286948-International-Porting)

[Porting a number To Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179348-Porting-a-Phone-Number-to-Twilio)

I understand, based on your country, this may not be an option.

Twilio does not have a way to register as a SIP client with another provider. It does offer the ability of using a Twilio hosted number (and thus the comment on porting) to register a SIP client against or forward a PSTN call to a SIP User Agent.

Comment: You are right about that  Twilio does not have a way to register as a SIP client with another provider.  And I can forward a call to another phone number, for example, to Twilio hosted number at low cost. Thanks